# Looping through an array using Migrate Plus

Tags: migrations, 8

I'm trying to loop through an array (called "Attributes") in a JSON migration source, but I can't figure out how to do it. Here's a shortened sample of my data source:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "ST00000002",
    "Title": "Fast & Furious 9",
    "Attributes": [
      "0000000013",
      "0000000015"
    ]
  }
]
```

My ultimate goal is to check certain checkbox/boolean fields based on those attribute values, but I can't figure out how to handle each of the attributes individually.

Things I have tried so far:

- Using `single_value` and `multiple_values`
- Using the custom `Deepen` process plugin (as seen on [this issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/255726/99075))
- Using `sub_process`
- Using the `static_map` plugin (to do something like this:

```
map:
    '0000000015': 1
default_value: 0
```

- Using `skip_on_value` with `not_equals: true`
- Using countless combinations of the above functions

I feel like this can't possibly be as difficult as I'm making it, so I hope someone can help me out. Thank you so much.

Comment: Migrate's YML is not really tailored to contain a lot of logic, I don't think there is anything built-in right now to solve this easily. While some weird logic with `concat` and `str_replace` + `regex` option might do the trick, I would advise to create a process plugin that acts as a wrapper to PHP's `in_array`

Comment: Extensive logic should go into process plugin(s), yes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. I got it to work by creating a custom process plugin using "in_array", as suggested. If anyone's interested, here's the plugin I created:

```
namespace Drupal\migrate_veezi\Plugin\migrate\process;

use Drupal\migrate\ProcessPluginBase;
use Drupal\migrate\MigrateException;
use Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutableInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;

/**
 * Check if value exists in array
 *
 * @MigrateProcessPlugin(
 *   id = "in_array"
 * )
 *
 * To check if value is in array, use the following:
 *
 * @code
 * field_text:
 *   plugin: in_array
 *   source: array
 *   search: 'string'
 * @endcode
 *
 */

class InArray extends ProcessPluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function transform($value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrate_executable, Row $row, $destination_property) {

    $search = $this->configuration['search'];

    if ($search) {
      if (is_array($value) || $value instanceof \Traversable) {
        return in_array($search, $value);
      }
      else {
        throw new MigrateException(sprintf('%s is not traversable', var_export($value, TRUE)));
      }
    }
    else {
      throw new MigrateException(sprintf('search value is not set'));
    }
  }

}
```

And then I used it like this:

```
field_closed_caption:
    -
      plugin: single_value
      source: attributes
    -
      plugin: in_array
      search: '0000000007'
```